# Testing child object by the ID of parent Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, parent, katalon-studio

So I am using a dynamic object and I can receive an API that lists all of the object's properties such as ID in one page, but that ID is the ID of a frame layout that is not interactable and only contains child such as textbox or error message.

what I'm trying to achieve is to know the properties of that parent object so that I can try to interact with the child, for example, the textbox EditText inside. I am able to interact with the child by using the XPath but haven't found a way to determine the parent by the determined ID.

I am trying to make automatic testing that only uses the API as a reference point to check what is the object to test so that in the future I don't have to change the test script in case of any changes in the configuration.

[image: object layout]

I can check the API for existing object properties like this:

```
      public static checkIfExistForm1(String code){

    def response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject("Object Repository/WebService"))
    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.getResponseBodyContent())

    for(int i = 0;i < json.page.form.fieldset.size(); i++){
        if(code.contentEquals(json.page.form.fieldset[i].control[0].id)){
            return true;
            break
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then I can make some kind of method to get the child of that object and try to interact with it

for example with this method I can select an object by XPath

```
public  static getObjectID(String code){
            //considering i know that this is the child, or creating another validation
            //the child(EditText) also has ID "content-desc" that i can use
    String dynamicIdPath = '//*[@content-desc="%s"]'
    String xpath = String.format(dynamicIdPath,code)
    TestObject to = new TestObject()
    to.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, xpath)
    return to
}
```

any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Could you put an example of the json and the html?

Comment: And to find a parent with xpath you can use `your_xpath/..` or `your_xpath/parent::*`

Comment: @Royce sorry for late reply, the json example looks like this : [link]https://imgur.com/a/Jz5t11D
and im i think i cant give u html since im not the one making this.

but also do u have any example for finding object that has a specific element such as "content-desc = "inputName" ? im still relatively new in Katalon and any eaxmples wouuld be great

Comment: To find a element based on xpath you can use : `WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc="inputName"]"))`. Do not forget that Selenium code can be use in Katalon.